# JSONArray converts response null elements to "null"

Tags: json, string, android-studio, kotlin, null

Trying to handle the response from API in Android Studio by using Kotlin. When converting the response of server from string to json the `null` values are converted as `"null"`. If the value is `null` I want it as `null`. How to solve this problem?

Volley portion of the code:

```
val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                jsonList = JSONArray(response) }
```

Response of the server:

```
[
    {
        "id": 213,
        "dummy": null
    }
]
```

Call as Json

```
jsonList.getJSONObject(0).get("dummy")
```

Result of call:

[image: Result of call]

As a result the below code will return `"null"` which is totally useless.

```
jsonList.getJSONObject(0).get("dummy")?.toSting()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like

```
jsonList.getJSONObject(0).get("dummy")?:""
```

if the result value is null it return empty string,

and if you want to get null you should remove  **.toString()**

Answer (score 1):

You can check

```
jsonList.getJSONObject(0).get("dummy") == JSONObject.NULL
```

It will hold true in your case

So you could do something like this

```
val dummy = jsonList.getJSONObject(0).get("dummy")
val dummyString = if (dummy == JSONObject.NULL) null else dummy.toString()
```